# Set Height of vertical Line

Tags: android, layout

i have some layout issues and dont know how to solve it.

Here is my layout (arranged in RelativeLayout): http://goo.gl/GxFTq

The visible black lines are created in my xml like

```
<View android:background="#000000"
      android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
      android:layout_below="@+id/lblCaption"
      android:id="@+id/view0"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_height="2dp"/>
```

i added the red and green lines with gimp to describe my problem.
the horizontal line on the right should be located in the middle between the vertical line on the top and the bottom of the display.
it should be like

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" + distance between the top of the display to vertical line on top
```

(see green lines on my pic)

Any tips? (Possible solutions in xml or programmatically - doesn't matter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This New Code

```
<View
android:id="@+id/view0"
android:layout_width="2dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/lblCaption"
android:background="#000000" />
```

Comment: Ha! :) Your first code has brought me to the same idea. i simply created a "invisible" view with android:layout_width="0dp". Thanks :)